# Its is better to create class lib or portable class lib?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dll, portable-class-library

I have to use some API in my project and for that my boss asked me to create lib for that API. Its .Net project and may be in future it may have Android app. But for now he wants me to create lib in c# by hitting on API. Can you suggest me should I start with portable Class lib or class library?

This is the API for which i have create lib 
http://api.synapsepay.com/v2.0/docs/user-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portable class library is the best choice. PCL is for creating code that can be used on multiple platforms in the .NET family. PCL may be useful later if you're planning on using something like Xamarin to publish for android, but isn't useful for anything that doesn't pertain to .NET right on creation.

Comment: Do you know any best tutorial, I am new to .net so for structure or reference. I have already created lib in python i just want to make similar structure. SO if you provide any link then that will be help full –

Comment: This will give you a good idea: [Creating a class library](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/61b832/creating-class-library-in-visual-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Portable class library if you want features of that library to work cross platform and to save you time from re-developing your library in the future for cross platform use.

Comment: Do you know any best tutorial, I am new to .net so for structure or reference. I have already created lib in python i just want to make similar structure. SO if you provide any link then that will be help full

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should go to PCL just for now. Due to Microsoft's poor design, a PCL profile provides much less APIs to consume and you often find things missing.

Don't give yourself extra pain for Android which you won't support in a minute. When the time comes, you can see if other way to share code is better.

For my own projects, there are library projects for different platforms which share the same files. That still works better than PCL.

Comment: so its better to use normal class lib?? Because in this project I m gonna hit on API and I have to manage errors.... I am new, so for me what ever is easy and thing available with more documentation and resources will be a good option... @Lex Li